# VBA how by external address return only sheet name and cell address?

Tags: vba, excel

I need to return only sheet and cells address.
This code:

```
SthRange.Adddress(external:=True)
```

Will return Workbook name, sheet and cells address. How can I return only sheet and cells?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the `Range.Address` function always returns a string in format `[Workbook]Worksheet!range` you could use string functions to trim the workbook off by trimming off everything up to and including the first ] character from the front of the string as shown below.

```
Dim strAddress As String
strAddress = SthRange.Address(External:=true)
strAddress = Right(strAddress, Len(strAddress)-InStr(strAddress, "]"))
```

If you're going to do this regularly you could add a quick function to your VBA project like this

```
Public Function SheetAndRange(ByVal FullAddress As String) As String
    SheetAndRange = Right(FullAddress, Len(FullAddress) - InStr(FullAddress, "]"))
End Function
```

Which would allow you to get your desired result as below:

```
strSomeString = SheetAndRange(SthRange.Address(External:=true))
```

Answer (score 1):

From [MrExcel](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/612832-decompose-excel-external-address-into-workbook-name-worksheet-name-cell-address.html) you can do this using the parent of the range.  If this is slow then you will have to break down the address string (also shown in linked example)

```
Dim FullAddressString as Strng
FullAddressString = "[Book1]Sheet1!$A$1"

MsgBox "is in Book " & Range(FullAddressString).Parent.Parent.Name
MsgBox "is in sheet " & Range(FullAddressString).Parent.Name
MsgBox "is in range" & Range(FullAddressString).Address
```

Comment: I found that for this technique to work one has to specify `Application.Range(...` because otherwise `Range` is implicitly the method of the active worksheet which can't process external addresses.